# LED Indicator not working in ThingsBoard Dashboard

Tags: widget, iot, dashboard, thingsboard

I am unable to get the LED Indicator widget in my dashboard to turn on/off.

I tried passing boolean values as telemetry data. If the value was true, the indicator should turn green (on). If the value was false, the indicator should turn red (off). I passed these as telemetry data based on which the widget functions. I want this widget to serve as an activity indicator for my device.

Answer (score 0):

I myself discovered the solution while toying around with the widget.

In the appearance tab of the Widget settings, head to the "value settings" panel and uncheck the "Perform RPC device status check" option.

Select the "Subscribe for Timeseries" option under the "Retrieve led status value using method" drop-down box.

Enter the timeseries key which contains the LED status value of the device

Save and continue. You will find that the LED indicator works exactly as expected.

If you have any further questions, feel free to ask! :)